# I want to get a rect from my contextual popup menu

Tags: c++, mfc, contextmenu, popupmenu

I asked the question a few days ago.

Then I succeeded the process of My button and contextual menu.

The process is like this.

[image]

1. When the mouse point is hovering on Button A, Show the popup menu (1) and (2).
2. When the mouse point is leaving from Button A, Close the all popup menu.

This is trouble because when the mouse point is hovering on my popup menu (1) or (2), close the all popup menu. I want to except the area of popup menu.

So I've tried to get rect of my popup menu and add exception from the Process 2. How can I get it?

※ P.S 1 : I used `TrackPopupMenu` function. In my opinion, It's impossible to get rect of popup menu until the end of `TrackPopupMenu` function(like selected menu or close popup menu). Am I right?

※ P.S 2 : I've tried to use `WM_MENUSELECT` Message. However it's still close the popup menu when the mouse point is leaved from Button A. So I'll try to use `GetMenuItemRect` function. How to use it?

Comment: It is very strange user interface concept. Menus pop up when it is unclear if user wants these and  disappear when it is unclear if user wants these to go away. Who wants it?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Someone doesn't want to click to open the popup menu and he just want to open popup menu when the mouse point is hovering on Button A. I agree with you.

Comment: I want the menu for A when I either press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or click on A (that means i press left mouse down and also release it there, not before I release it). Software with any other behavior I erase and curse with profanities when someone asks about it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib So I'm cursing with profanities him.

Comment: So, what you really want is an interactive tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the `TrackPopupMenu` function (which doesn't return a handle to the created menu), you can explicitly create and show a new `CMFCPopupMenu`.

Without knowing the full details of your implementation, you would do something like this:

```cpp
void MyClass:OnShowPopup(int Xpos, int Ypos) { // Xpos and Ypos are top-left corner
    CMDIFrameWndEx* frame = dynamic_cast<CMDIFrameWndEx *>(AfxGetMainWnd()); // Main frame
    CMenu menu;  menu.LoadMenu(IDM_MYPOPUP_ID); // Load from resources - or something
    CMFCPopupMenu *pPop = new CMFCPopupMenu; // New popup menu
    pPop->Create(this, Xpos, Ypos, menu.m_hMenu, FALSE, TRUE);
    CRect rc; pPop->GetWindowRect(&rc); // Here you have the popup menu's rectangle!!
    frame->OnShowPopupMenu(pPop); // This will activate the menu.
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: How can I use `frame->OnShowPopupMenu(pPop);`? Program is error because of that line.

Comment: What type of window is your main frame window? I think you need `CMDIFrameWndEx` to have this function - the older `CMDIFrameWnd` doesn't have it.

Comment: If you don't (or can't) use `CMDIFrameWndEx` then try using the code I gave up to the `pPop->GetWindowRect` call, then `delete pPop;` and call `::TrackPopupMenu()`. That should also work, as you will then have the width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: I really appreciate you.